# ReportViewer parameters, render pdf

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, rdlc

I want to render a report directly to pdf. I have an objectdatasource with 2 parameters. I obtain these parameters from a hiddenfield on the webform and from the datakeyname on a gridview. The report works when I load it in report viewer without rendering to pdf. When I place the code to render the report as pdf the parameters dont load i.e. the report renders as pdf but there are no details on the report. My code is below, any help appreciated. I placed the code in gridview_selectedindexchanged:

```
Protected Sub GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles GridView1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim ds1 As New seminarsTableAdapters.Sem1TableAdapter
    Dim rdssem As New ReportDataSource("seminars.sem1TableAdapter", ds1.GetData(aid:=HiddenField1.Value, semid:=GridView1.SelectedDataKey.Value))
    Dim reportsem As New LocalReport
    reportsem.ReportPath = "Report1.rdlc"
    Dim p1 As New ReportParameter("aid", HiddenField1.Value)
    Dim p2 As New ReportParameter("semid", GridView1.SelectedDataKey.Value().ToString)
    reportsem.SetParameters(New ReportParameter() {p1, p2})
    reportsem.DataSources.Add(rdssem)

    Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh()

    Dim warnings As Warning() = Nothing
    Dim streamids As String() = Nothing
    Dim mimeType As String = Nothing
    Dim encoding As String = Nothing
    Dim extension As String = Nothing
    Dim bytes As Byte()

    bytes = ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Render("PDF", Nothing, mimeType, encoding, extension, streamids, warnings)

    Response.Clear()
    Response.ContentType = mimeType
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=foo." + extension)
    Response.BinaryWrite(bytes)
    Response.End()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I overlooked the following line of code:

Dim rdssem As New ReportDataSource("seminars.sem1TableAdapter", ds1.GetData(aid......

it shoud read:

Dim rdssem As New ReportDataSource("**seminars.sem1**", ds1.GetData(aid.....

Working fine now!

Thanks!